# My new hard drive doesn't have rights on my old one?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, permissions, ssd

Until recently I had a 1 TB hard disk with Windows 7 on it, I have bought myself a SSD, removed the old harddisc and installed Windows 7 on my new one.

After that I put back the old hard disk, and formatted it, now I could use that as backup and to keep files on. Nice, right?

Well I was updating .Net framework through Windows update, when it stalled.  I noticed some space was used on one of the drives on my secondary 'previously primary' hard disk. Apparently it was the .Net framework, trying to save some temporary files on my secondary disc, because it was the one with the most space.

It was like it didn't get access. I cancled the installation and rebooted the computer. Now wanting to remove the temporary folder on my secondary harddisk. It told me.  "You don't have access by SYSTEM", I don't understand, my user is administrator, its the only user there is and at the same time I can remove and delete any other folder on that drive.

I'm gonna go a little pseudo here. But it feels as if the computer treats the old harddisk as protected from tampering by the new SSD.  Also, I feel I should mention, they are both listed as primary, ... primary 0 and primary 1. Both using SATA cable.

---

My old hard drive was partioned into 3 drives.

2 of them said the current owner was 'Administrator/myPCname' and the third one said the current owner was 'SYSTEM'

I changed them all into the only one that I could pick from the list, which is my user since the 'Administrators/myPCname' wasn't exactly wrong.. could it be that they were somehow still attached to the old OS?.. the fact is I named my computer the exact same thing as it was called before installing a new windows.. so I can't really tell if its an old ownership or not.

Also.. I'm currently logged in as 'myname' and I'm administrator.. now trying to delete the previously mentioned files.. it says 'you need access from 'myname' – and it can't delete..

That seems really messed up, I mean I'm logged in as the name it wants me to use.

Is there maybe someway I could reset all the users on my computer? Or create some default? I don't know – I just want it to take a form I have always known, from a standard Windows point of view.

Answer (score 4):

Seems the problem is related to NTFS' file system security. You must take ownership of your old files.

How to: [Take Ownership of a File or Folder](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753659.aspx)

Or the simplest way: [Add "Take Ownership" to Explorer Right-Click Menu in Win 7 or Vista - How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/)